# Resolving physical URLs from a webapp that uses react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working on a webapp which is being developed using REACT and REACT-ROUTER.
The type of history being used is the BrowserHistory.

The problem is inside my app I have an XMLHTTP request to an upload.php file on my server. 
The .php file resides in the root directory but the call is made from a react component that has the virtual URL: `hostname/pagename/add`
When I try to refer to the .php file it cannot be found because it is looking for it in `hostname/pagename/add/upload.php`
Here is the code that calls the upload.php file

```
this.getRequest(
       'upload.php', //Note: tried '/upload.php'  and '../../upload.php'
        formData,
        this.uploadResponse,  
        this.uploadError    
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I have come up with:

```
this.getRequest(
        window.location.origin+'/upload.php'
        formData,
        this.uploadResponse,  
        this.uploadError    
    )
```

If anyone has any other suggestions I would still like to hear them.